# How to Embedd List of Entites in android room?

Tags: java, android, persistence, android-room

I Want to Embed a list of some entity class within another entity
Like :

```
@Entity
public class FirstEntity() {}

@Entity
public class SecondEntity() {

@Embedded
List<FirstEntity> firstEntities ;

}
```

can anyone give me a solution with an example.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I had to create a new class like this

```
public class Wrapper {

    @Embedded
    public FirstEntity firstEntity;

    @Relation (parentColumn = columnOfFirstEntity, entityColumn = columnOfSecondEntity)
    public List<SecondEntity> secontEntities;

    //Insert getters and setters

}
```

You have to use Relations entity as list even if you have only a single item in it, just fetch and set the first element in the list if you have just one item in it.

Dao will something look like this

```
@Dao
public interface WrapperDao {

    @Query( "SELECT *  FROM FirstEntity" )
    public List<Wrapper> getAllWrappers();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a converter. I convert the list of objects into JSON string via the GSON library (so add the dependency in your gradle file) :

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

First create a Converter with the `@TypeConverter` annotation to convert your List (here my example with a class named Output) :

```
class OutputConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromOutputList(outputs: List<Output>?): String? {
        if (outputs == null) {
            return null
        }
        val gson = Gson()
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<Output>>() {}.type
        return gson.toJson(outputs, type)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toOutputList(outputString: String?): List<Output>? {
        if (outputString == null) {
            return null
        }
        val gson = Gson()
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<Output>>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson(outputString, type)
    }
}
```

Then you need to declare the Converter in your Database class :

```
@Database(entities = [(YourParentClass::class)], version = 1)
@TypeConverters(OutputConverter::class)
abstract class YourDataBase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun yourDao(): YourDao
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use joins for your problem instead of increase data redundancy. If you want learn goto https://www.guru99.com/sqlite-join.html#1. This way will be better i think.